# extract substring and convert to datetime python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe, `df`:

```
data = [{0: 18, 1: '(Responses) 17th Nov 20'},
        {0: 304, 1: '(Responses) 17th Nov 20'},
        {0: 1177, 1: '(Responses) 17th Nov 20'},
        {0: 899, 1: '(Responses) 17th Nov 20'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

0                1                                          
18    (Responses) 17th Nov 20
304   (Responses) 17th Nov 20
1177  (Responses) 17th Nov 20
899   (Responses) 17th Nov 20
```

Is there any efficient way to extract out `17th Nov 2020` and make it to a new `column[2]` as `17-11-2020` as date?

It can also be `1st` or `2nd` or `3rd` for other date.

Expected output:

```
0                1                 2                         
18    (Responses) 17th Nov 20   17-11-2020
304   (Responses) 17th Nov 20   17-11-2020
1177  (Responses) 17th Nov 20   17-11-2020
899   (Responses) 17th Nov 20   17-11-2020
```

Comment: `df[1].str.split(n=1, expand=True)`?

Comment: If we can see how the column was created, it might be possible to provide a more optimal solution that avoids this awkward uncleaned data.

Comment: @LainTaljuk `n=1` it only splits once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.split` and `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df[2] = pd.to_datetime(df[1].str.replace('\(Responses\) ', ''))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      0                        1          2
0    18  (Responses) 17th Nov 20 2020-11-17
1   304  (Responses) 17th Nov 20 2020-11-17
2  1177  (Responses) 17th Nov 20 2020-11-17
3   899  (Responses) 17th Nov 20 2020-11-17
```

Comment: Im getting Nan value instead

Comment: @user6308605 I edited my answer, please check again

Comment: I realised why I get Nan. The actual string is `Copy of BeAChampion (Responses) ` so it should be str[4], correct? But still getting Nan

Comment: @user6308605 I have a new edit on my answer check it out

Comment: @user6308605 We shouldn't use `split`, see my example of `replace`

Comment: df[2] = pd.to_datetime(df[1].str.replace(r'Copy of BeAChampion \(Responses\) ', '', regex=True)) works :D Thank you. DIdnt think of this easy way

Answer (score 0):

Just `split` your string with "(responses)" as your keyword, and then get the second element after split:

```
  df['new_column'] = df['1'].str.split("(responses)").str[1]
```